# Kendo UI MaskedTextBox - 0 width/height

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to use the Kendo UI MaskedTextBox. I use the MVC wrappers. I'm unable to get the widget to display. It always renders with a width/height of 0. The console shows no errors. Why is this happening? *(Yes, I know I could manually force the dimensions by specifying `HtmlAttributes`, but that shouldn't be necessary.)*

[image: textbox]

My code:

```
<div class="inputs">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone):
    @(Html.Kendo().MaskedTextBox()
        .Name(Html.NameFor(model => model.Phone).ToString())
        .Mask("(000) 000-0000")
        .PromptChar("#")
        .Value(Model.Phone)
    )
</div>
```

This is the generated code. The value is valid, I replaced it with 2s for privacy.

```
<div class="inputs">
    <label for="Phone">Phone</label>:
    <input id="Phone" name="Phone" value="(222) 222-2222" data-role="maskedtextbox" class="k-textbox" autocomplete="off">
    <script>
        jQuery(function(){jQuery("#Phone").kendoMaskedTextBox({"mask":"(000) 000-0000","promptChar":"#","rules":{}});});
    </script>
</div>
```

Chrome dev tools inspector shows the width and height being set to 2px and 6px, respectively, by `kendo.common-bootstrap.css`. These values are entirely the border and padding, the element itself is 0x0. The relevant selector code is below.

Width:

```
.k-autocomplete,
.k-combobox,
.k-datepicker,
.k-timepicker,
.k-datetimepicker,
.k-colorpicker,
.k-numerictextbox,
.k-dropdown,
.k-selectbox,
.k-textbox,
.k-toolbar .k-split-button {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12.4em;
  overflow: visible;
  border-width: 0;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Height:

```
input.k-textbox {
  height: 2.42em;
  text-indent: 0.8em;
  line-height: 1.6em;
}
```

Comment: This is not relevant to your problem, but why don't you use MaskedTextBoxFor?

Comment: @ataravati I haven't used the `For` variants anywhere on my site; I was learning Kendo and didn't want to complicate things. Now that I know what I'm doing it's obviously much easier, but it's not worth it to go back through and change all of them.

Comment: it is totally worth it to go back and change them all, in my opinion. It won't take more than 15 minutes of your time.

Comment: @ataravati Honest question: If I may ask, what is the major difference? I (think I) understand the difference between the standard and `For` variants, but why would it ultimately matter?

Comment: It's cleaner code. That's important.

Comment: Do you get the same behaviour in different browsers? Also, do you get any error messages in the Console?

Comment: @ataravati No, the same behavior occurs in Chrome and FF. The box displays in IE but it has no masking behavior whatsoever.

Comment: Do you get any error messages in the Console? Are you sure you're referencing all the required Kendo js files?

Comment: @ataravati Whoops, sorry. No messages in the console at all. I reference `jszip.min.js`, `kendo.custom.min.js` (MaskedTextBox is part of it), `kendo.aspnetmvc.min.js`, `kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css`, `kendo.bootstrap.min.css`, `kendo.mobile.common.css`, and `kendo.bootstrap.mobile.min.css`, in that order.